# Appending data to table from nested JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I'm having an issue appending JSON data to a simple HTML table using the `tr.apppend` jQuery function after clicking a button. I've checked the console in Firebug and i'm receiving the correct JSON data but somewhere along the line it's not iterating through the nested data and appending to the HTML table.

**My JSON data format:**

`{"response": {"system": {"database": "3"}, "songs": [{"artistid": "1", "song": "Umbrella"}, {"artistid": "1", "song": "We Found Love"}]}}`

I've tried to add `[i]` to various parts of my `tr.append` data array but none seem to be working. Is the [i] in the correct position or does nested JSON data need a different method of working?

```
$.getJSON(APIurl + name + '&format=json&start=0&results=2', function(data) {
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<td class='artist'>" + data.songs[i].artistid + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td class='title'>" + data.songs[i].song + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + "<button class='send' type='submit'>Add to database</button>" + "</td>");
    $('#table').append(tr);
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i)` to `for (var i = 0; i < data.songs.length; ++i)`

The length property is called on the root object when it needs to be called on the songs property/array.